# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} $

Tags: real-analysis, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Can we find $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} \quad$$

This problem asked me my friend about a year ago, but I didn't know how to attack problem. Now, I am interesting in solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: Smells divergent to me.  Are you sure you have it all?

Comment: Silly me. Yes, this diverges. I will change a little bit question.

Comment: In principle, I am interesting in asymptotic behavior, so it's not big problem if it diverges.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to find the asymptotics by using the classic asymptotic estimates for the binomials and approximating with an integral.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you show that way (if it gives better result than N.S.) ?

Comment: @Cortizol I don't have a ton of time to, but I'll see if I can sometime this weekend.  In the meantime, the actual behavior might be on the order of $2^{n/2}\sqrt[4]{n}$ - the article at http://members.chello.cz/kotesovec/math_articles/kotesovec_binomial_asymptotics.pdf has a result on $\sum{n\choose k}^p$ that they claim for $p\geq 1$ but that could hold for $p\gt 0$ (I can't really see where they use $p\geq 1$ in their admittedly somewhat confusing argument)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I know this has been looming over your head for months now. I have added an asymptotic approximation so that you can sleep better :-) Does my result agree with the article for $p=\frac12$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I was able to download the article and indeed, my answer agrees for $x=1$ and $p=\frac12$. I think the method I use below should be able to get their result as well.

Comment: Related MathOverflow post: [Sum of square roots of binomial coefficients](http://mathoverflow.net/q/258711)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an asymptotic approximation rather than an evaluation.

If we take the first difference of the log of $\sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}$, we get
$$
\frac12\log\left(\frac{n-k+1}{k}\right)\tag{1}
$$
which vanishes when $k\sim n/2$.

If we take the second difference of the log of $\sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}$, we get
$$
\frac12\log\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)-\frac12\log\left(\frac{n-k+2}{n-k+1}\right)\sim-\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2(n-k+1)}\tag{2}
$$
This is approximately
$$
-\frac2n\tag{3}
$$
where the first difference vanishes.

Approximating the sum by a Gaussian, gives the value of the sum to be asymptotic to
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\sqrt{\textstyle\binom{n}{n/2}}}^{\begin{array}{c}\text{account}\\\text{for the}\\\text{maximum}\end{array}}\cdot\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/n}\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\begin{array}{c}\text{account}\\\text{for second}\\\text{difference}\end{array}}
&\sim2^{n/2}\left(\frac2{\pi n}\right)^{1/4}\cdot\sqrt{\pi n}\\
&=2^{n/2}(2\pi n)^{1/4}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
For $n=100$, the sum is $5.62976892\times10^{15}$ and $(4)$ gives $5.63695737\times10^{15}$.

For $n=1000$, the sum is $2.91399232\times10^{151}$ and $(4)$ gives $2.91435733\times10^{151}$.

As $n$ gets larger, the approximation gets better.

Answer (score 8):

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} \right)^2 \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}=2^n$$

Thus

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

Also, by C-S

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} \right)^2 \leq (n+1)2^n$$

thus

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}\leq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \sqrt{n+1}$$

Comment: Stupid me. I change question. Sorry.

Comment: I think this makes more sense as a comment than an answer based on what the OP wants.

Comment: @EricNaslund This answered the Original question, before it was edited...

Comment: @N.S. I am aware of that, but it was reasonably clear that the OP wanted something different. A comment would have sufficed to alert the OP so he could clarify and say what he actually wants, as racing to be the "fastest gun in the west" and post an answer in under $4$ minutes seems unnecessary. Anyway, as is the current bounds fit the question quite nicely and you have my +1.

Comment: Can we find some asymptotic behavior with $\sim$ ? I mean, it looks for me that there is a plenty space between $2^{n/2}$ and $2^{n/2} \sqrt{n+1}$ when $n$ is arbitrary large.

Answer (score 4):

For any positive power $p$, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^p \sim \dfrac{2^{np}}{\sqrt{p}}\cdot\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)^{(1-p)/2} $,

Making, $n \mapsto 2n$,

We have, $\displaystyle \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n-k}}{\binom{2n}{n}} = \dfrac{n}{n+k}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1-\frac{j}{n}}{1+\frac{j}{n}} = \dfrac{n}{n+k}e^{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\log\frac{1-j/n}{1+j/n}}$

and form taylor expansion at $t=0$, $\log \dfrac{1-t}{1+t} = -2t - \dfrac{2x^3}{3}+O(t^5)$,

so, $0 < -2t - \log\dfrac{1-t}{1+t} = O(t^3) $ for, $0 < t < 1/2$.

It sufices to look at the central $n^{2/3}$-terms,

since, $\displaystyle \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n-k}}{\binom{2n}{n}} = \dfrac{n}{n+k}\large{e^{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\log\frac{1-j/n}{1+j/n}}}$ $ = \begin{cases}(1+O(n^{-1/3}))e^{-k^2/n} & \textrm{ for } k\le n^{2/3} \\ O(e^{-n^{1/3}})  & \textrm{ for } k>n^{2/3}\end{cases}$

Hence, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n-k}^p}{\binom{2n}{n}^p} = (1+O(n^{-1/3}))\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^{2/3}} e^{-pk^2/n} + o(1) = (1+O(n^{-1/3}))\int_1^{n^{2/3}} e^{-pt^2/n}\,dt + O(1)$

$$\sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{n\pi}{p}}$$

Using Stirling Approximation we have, $\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n} \sim \dfrac{4^{n}}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$

Hence, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^p \sim \dfrac{2^{np}}{\sqrt{p}}\cdot\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)^{(1-p)/2} $

Comment: +1 The sum you are esitmating is a special case ($x=1$) of the formula that Steven Stadnicki linked to in a comment to the question.