# An asymptotic expression of sum of powers of binomial coefficients.

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $k$ be a fixed positive number and $n$ an integer increasing to infinity. Then  $$\sum_{\nu =0}^n \binom{n}{\nu}^k \sim \frac{2^{kn}}{\sqrt{k}} \left( \frac{2}{\pi n} \right)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}.$$  This is from Polya's *Problems and Theorems in Analysis*, Vol. 1, Part II, Problem 40. The proof provided in the book is too simple. It says details can be found in Jordan's *Cours d'Analyse*, Vol.2, 3rd Ed, pp. 218-221. However, I cannot find this edition online, and what's worse, there is not any English translations. Can anyone give a proof in detail?

Comment: To eliminate any ambiguity, $C_n^\nu = \binom{\nu}{n}=\frac{\nu !}{n!(\nu-n)!}?$

Comment: Well, as usual, $C_{n}^{\nu }=\left( \begin{matrix}
   n  \\
   \nu   \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\frac{n!}{\nu !\cdot \left( n-\nu  \right)!}$.

Comment: @EclipseSun see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/573537/129017) if this helps :)

Comment: Exercise 9.18 of [Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/gkp.html) by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik may be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That kind of asymptotics follows from the Central Limit Theorem. If we consider the binomial random variable $X=B(n,1/2)$ as the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli trials, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{n}{4}, \qquad \operatorname{Var}[X]=\frac{n}{4}$$
from which the approximation:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{n/2+r}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{2r^2}{n}\right).\tag{1}$$
By considering the $k$-th power of both terms and summing over $r\in[-n/2,n/2]$ (the main contribute is clearly given by the central binomial coefficient and its neighbours) we get:
$$\sum_{r=-n/2}^{n/2}\binom{n}{n/2+r}^k \approx 2^{kn}\left(\frac{2}{\pi n}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}}\sum_{r=-n/2}^{n/2}\exp\left(-\frac{2kr^2}{n}\right)\tag{2}$$
and the claim follows from approximating the last sum with:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{2kx^2}{n}\right)\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2k}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I know that (1) is correct, and from (2) I can derive (3). But I have problem to understand the validity to take $k$-th power of (1) and sum them up. Why is the asymptotic expression still valid after this operation?

Comment: @EclipseSun Excellent reaction... :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but is too long for the usual comment format.
I have access to the reference given in the OP, so I looked it up,
but I was disappointed.

In those pages 218 to 221, C. Jordan nowhere considers sums 
$\sum_{\nu} \binom{n}{\nu}^k$ for $k$ other than $1$. The strongest result 
shown there is a form of the CLT : Jordan shows that for $p\in[0,1]$, 
if $(\lambda_{n})$ is an integer sequence such that 
$\frac{\lambda_n}{n^a}$ is bounded for some $a<1$, then

$$
\sum_{\nu=\frac{n}{2}-\lambda_n}^{\frac{n}{2}+\lambda_n}
\binom{n}{\nu}p^\nu(1-p)^{n-\nu} \sim_{n\to+\infty} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi p(1-p)n}} \int_{-\lambda_n}^{\lambda_n} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2p(1-p)n}}dx
$$

The key ingredient of the proof is that as $\lambda_n$ is sufficiently small
compared to $n$, we can use a Stirling approximation $\log(t!)\sim (t+\frac{1}{2})\log(t)-t+\frac{\log(2\pi)}{2}$ for all the integers $t$ we need.

The only way this can help in my view is that it suggests showing something
like

$$
\sum_{\nu =0}^n \binom{n}{\nu}^k \sim \sum_{\nu =\frac{n}{2}-n^a}^{\frac{n}{2}+n^a}\binom{n}{\nu}^k 
$$

for some $a<1$ depending perhaps on $k$. That’s still a big "if".