# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k =0}^n \binom{n}{k}^t} .$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to find the following limit for $t\geq1$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k =0}^n \binom{n}{k}^t}.$$

I suspect this can be solved using generating functions but did not make any headway.

Looking at this thread, [Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n).
<s>I'm guessing the answer to be $t$.</s> As pointed out by [Gary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83800/gary), the limit is $4$ when $t = 2$ and the appropriate guess would be $2^t$.

Comment: For $t=2$, you would get $4 \neq t$ since $\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}$. The general answer should be $2^t$ based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976777/an-asymptotic-expression-of-sum-of-powers-of-binomial-coefficients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $n$ is even *(we can deal with odd cases as well, but it's a little messier)*, writing $n=2m$. Then, since for all $0\leq k\leq 2m$ we have
$\binom{2m}{k}\leq \binom{2m}{m}$, we get
$$
\binom{2m}{m}^t\leq \sum_{k=0}^{2m} \binom{2m}{k}^t \leq (2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}^t \tag{1} 
$$
and, using standard estimates for the Binomial coefficient *(Stirling's inequality)* we have
$$
\binom{2m}{m} \operatorname*{\sim}_{m\to\infty} \frac{C}{\sqrt{m}}\cdot 2^{2m} \tag{2}
$$
for some constant $C>0$. Combining (1) and (2) and taking the $2m$-th root, we get by the squeeze theorem that, as $m\to\infty$, the limit is $\boxed{2^t}$.