Combinatorial formula for quantity of strings
Let $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ be a string of length $n$, where $x_i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$. That is there are $k^n$ strings of this type. How many of them have a substring of identical values of length at least $m (m \leq n)$? I know that the answer is $$\sum_{i \geq 0, j \geq 0, i+jm \leq n-m}k^{n+1-m-jm}(k-1)^j(-1)^j\binom{i+j}{i}-\sum_{i \geq 0, j \geq 0, i+jm \leq n-m-1}k^{n-m-jm}(k-1)^j(-1)^j\binom{i+j}{i}$$but I don't know how to get this formula. I know it has to be used inclusion-exclusion formula and generating functions, but I can't see how exactly I can apply them. Help please

So $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$  is an n-tuple from ${1,2,...,k}\times\cdots\times {1,2,...,k}={1,2,...,k}^n$ , and your question is, given $m≤n$, how many elements of ${1,2,...,k}^n$  are of the form $(x_1...,x_j,...,x_{j+m},...,x_n)$, where $x_i=x_{i+1}$ for $j≤i≤j+m−1$. Is that right? By substring, you mean $m$ consecutive elements of the n-tuple $(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Double typo: lenght --> length

@omharmoni yes, thas is right. By substring i mean $m$ consequetive elements, yes

@Kiy To your now deleted question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976777/an-asymptotic-expression-of-sum-of-powers-of-binomial-coefficients

@Gary thank you

We get from first principles that the number of strings with no run of
$m$ identical values is given by the OGF
$$\sum_{q\ge 1} k (k-1)^{q-1} (z+\cdots+z^{m-1})^q
\\ = k \sum_{q\ge 1} (k-1)^{q-1} z^q (1+\cdots+z^{m-2})^q
\\ = k z \frac{1-z^{m-1}}{1-z}
\sum_{q\ge 1} (k-1)^{q-1} z^{q-1} (1+\cdots+z^{m-2})^{q-1}
\\ = k z \frac{1-z^{m-1}}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-(k-1)z(1-z^{m-1})/(1-z)}
\\ = k z \frac{1-z^{m-1}}{1-z-(k-1)z(1-z^{m-1})}
\\ = k z \frac{1-z^{m-1}}{1-kz+(k-1)z^m}.$$
Extracting the coefficient on $z^n$
$$k [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-kz+(k-1)z^m}
- k [z^{n-m}] \frac{1}{1-kz+(k-1)z^m}.$$
Now we have
$$[z^p] \frac{1}{1-kz+(k-1)z^m}
= [z^p] \frac{1}{1-z(k-(k-1)z^{m-1})}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^p [z^{p-q}] (k-(k-1)z^{m-1})^q
= \sum_{q=0}^p [z^q] (k-(k-1)z^{m-1})^{p-q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/(m-1)\rfloor}
[z^{(m-1)q}] (k-(k-1)z^{m-1})^{p-q(m-1)}
= \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/(m-1)\rfloor}
[z^q] (k-(k-1)z)^{p-q(m-1)}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/(m-1)\rfloor}
{p-q(m-1)\choose q} (-1)^q (k-1)^q k^{p-qm}.$$
We thus have for at least one run of length $m$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{align*}
k^n - k \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/(m-1)\rfloor}
{n-1-q(m-1)\choose q} (-1)^q (k-1)^q k^{n-1-qm}
\\ + k \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (n-m)/(m-1)\rfloor}
{n-m-q(m-1)\choose q} (-1)^q (k-1)^q k^{n-m-qm}.
\end{align*}}$$
This is for $m\ge 2.$ With at least one run of length one we find $k^n$ by inspection.

could you explain please why the number of strings with no run of $m$ identical values is given by $\sum_{q \geq 1}k(k-1)^{q-1}(z+...+z^{m-1})^q$? And why the coefficient on $z^n$ is exactly what you have written?

The variable $z$ encodes the length of the run in its exponent. Multiplying we get the total sum of run lengths, which is the length of the string. Assigning letters to the block of runs we have $k$ choices for the first block and $k-1$ choices for the remaining blocks, which must not repeat the value of the preceding block.

The initial sum represents a classification of the set of strings by the number $q$ of runs.

So the coeffitient on $z^n$ in the expression $\sum_{q \geq 1}k(k-1)^{q-1}(z+z^2+...+z^{m-1})^q$ is equal to quantity of strings of length $n$ that have no substring of identical values of length $m$ and we substract this from $k^n$ and get the answer, right?

I got the solution, thank you so much!

Thanks. Yes the term $z+\cdots+z^{m-1}$ represents a run/block of length less than $m.$

Disclaimer: This answer only derives the generating function, not how it can be used towards the formula. But I'll post this already, if it gives some ideas.
Let's find the generating function $G(x)$ of the sequences containing a run of at least $m$. Let each letter have weight $x$, so the coefficient of $x^n$ counts the number of words of length $n$.
Divide the sequences into two categories: those that have the run of $m$ identicals at the beginning and those where the (first) $m$-run is not at the beginning.
Then $G(x)$ is the sum of the GFs of those.
The first category is easy: a word is $m$ (identical) letters (which we can choose in $k$ ways) followed by any sequence of letters. So we have (by the "product-rule")
$$
kx^m \frac{1}{1-kx}.
$$
Words in second category consist of a non-empty beginning that is a sequence of runs of length at most $m-1$, that ends on a different letter to the one that makes the first $m$-run, followed by the $m$-run and by any sequence. The $m$-run has $k$ choices, the previous (which we require to be different) $k-1$ choices. Let's find the GF of these beginning sequences. Denote it by $B(x)$. A beginning ends in a run of at most length $m-1$ and has in front either the empty string or word of same type (note: the next symbol always has $k-1$ choices since it must change). So
$$
B(x) = (1+B(x))(k-1)(x+x^2+\dots+x^{m-1}) = (1+B(x))(k-1)\frac{x-x^m}{1-x}
$$
This gives
$$
B(x) = (k-1)\frac{x-x^m}{1-kx+(k-1)x^m}.
$$
Thus
$$
G(x) = kx^m \frac{1}{1-kx} + B(x) kx^m \frac{1}{1-kx}
= kx^m \frac{1-x}{(1-kx)(1-kx+(k-1)x^m)}.
$$
